# Textbox in Datagrid updating source automatically, should be explicit.

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

Before I begin, I know there are similar questions, and [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766983/why-is-wpf-updatesourcetrigger-not-binding-explicitly?rq=1) are almost exactly the same problem, but I ask again because what worked 3 years ago is not working for me today, and I imagine enough has changed in that time to warrant an extra question on the topic.

I have a data grid with a column of Textboxes in it, and I want the user to be able to edit the values without any properties being updated until a button is pressed. Here is the XAML for the column in question:

```
<!--Begin Problem Area-->
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Margin="0" Padding="-2" MaxHeight="29" Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
<!--End Problem Area-->
```

As of right now, my save button does not work, but that is a different issue entirely. If I understand correctly, `UpdateSourceTrigger = Explicit` should ensure that the value does not update until it is explicitly told to through a command, e.g. not when it loses focus or the property is changed.

I have a button that writes the current values to the Console, here is the code:

```
private void HistoryButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Device foo in ConfigurationParameterCollection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value for {0}: {1}", foo.Name, foo.Value);
    }           

}
```

This prints all the values correctly:

```
Value for Property 1: 12345
Value for Property 2: Pizza
Value for Property 3: False
Value for Fourth Property: John Smith
Value for Property 4: True
Value for Property 5: False
Value for Property 6: True
Value for Property 7: False
Value for Property 8: True
Value for Property 9: False
Value for Property 10: True
Value for Property 11: Twelve
Value for Property 12: True
Value for Property 13: 5000
Value for Property 14: Success
Value for Property 15: True
Value for Property 16: True
```

However, when I change the value of one of these through the datagrid and press the button again:

```
Value for Property 1: 12345
Value for Property 2: Pizza
Value for Property 3: False
Value for Fourth Property: John Smith
Value for Property 4: True
Value for Property 5: False
Value for Property 6: True
Value for Property 7: False
Value for Property 8: True
Value for Property 9: False
Value for Property 10: True
Value for Property 11: Twelve
Value for Property 12: True
Value for Property 13: 5000
Value for Property 14: Success
Value for Property 15: True
Value for Property 16: False
```

Note how Property 16 has changed from true to false, even though I have not told it to update the source (or at least, I don't think I have).

I have no idea what could be causing this. I thought it may be because I was implementing the `BindableBase` class or the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, but I changed my Properties to look like this:

```
private string value;
public string Value
{
    get { return value; }
    set { this.value = value; }
}
```

And no luck there. Aside from that, I have no clue what could be causing this, unless it is an inherent property of a Data Grid, or something like that. In any case, a solution would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `Explicit` has no effect in a `DataGrid`. If you don't set the source property, how do you expect the typed in value to show up in the `TextBlock` in the `CellTemplate` that binds to the `Value` property when you leave the edit mode of the cell? Where are you supposed to store the new values if you don't set the source properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `Explicit` has no effect in a `DataGrid`. If you don't set the source property, how do you expect the typed in (new) value to show up in the `TextBlock` in the `CellTemplate` that binds to the `Value` property (that you never set) when you leave the edit mode of the cell?

Where are you supposed to store the new values if you don't set the source properties?

What you should do is to implement the `IEditableObject` interface in your `Device` data class and keep track of the original values as well as the new values. Something like this:

```
public class Device : IEditableObject
{
    private string _originalValue;
    private string _value;
    public string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = value; }
    }

    public string OriginalValue => _originalValue;

    public void BeginEdit()
    {
        //store the original value(s)
        _originalValue = _value;
    }

    public void CancelEdit() { }

    public void EndEdit() { }

    public void Commit()
    {
        _originalValue = _value;
    }
}
```

You can then call the `Commit()` method of the `Device` when the `Button` is clicked to persist the new values:

```
private void HistoryButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Device foo in ConfigurationParameterCollection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Value for {0}: {1}", foo.Name, foo.OriginalValue);
        foo.Commit();
    }
}
```

The point is that you need to store both values, i.e. the original one and the new one.

Comment: I am gathering all of my devices from several collections, so how would I go about setting the values for every single device in every single collection? I have tried setting the values equal in the constructor of `Device`, but I must be doing it wrong, or it does not work.

Comment: Each Device needs to store an original and a current value of each property that you edit in the DataGrid.

Comment: I understand that. If I understand correctly, I want to begin with Value and OriginalValue being equal, then one changes with each edit, but the other only changes when I tell it to. That makes sense, but I can't figure out how to get Value and OriginalValue equal in the first place, without manually assigning both every time I create a new Device

Comment: Inject the Device with the original values when you create an instance of it instead of setting the Value property initially?

Comment: The only way I know to do that would be through the constructor, but any code I put in the constructor is executed before the object is fully constructed. Because of that, I can't just do `OriginalValue = Value`, because at the time that is executed, `Value` is not assigned

Comment: What I mean is that you should pass *one* value to the constructor and do `_originalValue = passedInValue; _value = passedInValue;`.